# ASP.NET Razor Entity Framework Null reference exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is the code that is causing the problem, it is inside the view:

```
@{
    if(item.Contract_Type != null)
    {
        dangerhtml = (item.Contract_Type == "Premium") ? "class=\"warning\"" : "";
    }
}
<td @dangerhtml>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contract_Type)
</td>
```

This code is sitting inside a foreach:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
..etc
}
```

It is throwing a NullReferenceException on the if line. The code works fine if I remove all the above and just do:

```
<td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contract_Type)
</td>
```

But I am looking to set the class for the cell based on the contents of the item.Contract_Type

Any help appreciated!

Comment: it looks like the object "item" is null. Can you show us where you initialize that object?

Comment: I've added to the original post

Comment: have you added "@model IList<TypeOfYourModel>" in your view? (As described here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor)

Comment: I'd assume it's already implict as the information is already on the page and it works and populates, I just want to do some logic surrounding it with the if?

Comment: can you show us the whole page? Might be easier to see the problem then.

Comment: try `<td @if(item.Contract_Type != null){<text>class="warning"</text>}>` and if you still get same error, item is null.

Comment: Yeh that threw an exception too. I'm not quite sure how it can be null, this is populating a table with 250 rows which populates fine with @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contract_Type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that item is null, as Luke has already mentioned and that @Html.DisplayFor will just swallow this.

Why don't you just add following where clause to prevent null-items from being processed:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(i => i != null))
{
  ..etc
}
```

Or you can null-check the item before checking the Contract_Type to prevent the NullReferenceException from occurring:

```
if(item != null && item.Contract_Type != null)
{
  dangerhtml = (item.Contract_Type == "Premium") ? "class=\"warning\"" : "";
}
```

But maybe the best approach would be to ensure that no null-object is written to the Model-collection before passing it to the view..